# Outlook sso token version mis match with new App Registration (Preview)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, outlook-addin, office-js

I have built an Outlook addin to show SharePoint data using Graph Api ([refrence](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-NodeJS-SSO)) . For this registered an APP under **app.dev.microsoft.com** site to get Outlook token using **getAccessTokenAsync()** method in the office.js library.

This sample works as expected it returned Outlook token v2.0. This token helps me to get the Graph Token V2.0 using on-behalf-flow.

When I registered the app under the **Azure Portal** -> **App Registration (Preview)** which is a new option to register v2.0 tokens and replaces the app.dev.microsoft.com, the **getAccessTokenAsync()** method returns the v1.0 token. So, JWT token validation fails and I am unable to get the graph token v2.0.

Is anybody knows, is this expected behavior in future or a bug?

Comment: Which **Supported account types** did you choose for your application? you need to use **Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts** : See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-a-new-application-using-the-azure-portal

Comment: Yes, I have choose "Accounts in any organization directory and personal Microsoft Accounts" option as we need to support multi tenant scenario.

Comment: This is probably a bug. Microsoft is investigating.

Comment: In the "App Registration (Preview)" experience, please open the application and go to the "Manifest" section.  Can you tell us the value of "accessTokenAcceptedVersion"?  It would also help us if you could tell us the "appId" of the application and the field called "signInAudience" which are also in the manifest.

Comment: In the manifest file the values is as **"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null** and **"id": "4fc63f8a-7eab-444e-922c-a308ceab9b2c"** and **"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs"**. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your app manifest should show the following:
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",

This will happen if you choose "Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts" as Supported Account Type when you are creating the app.
Please re-create the application with right selection and you should be able to get a V2 token.